# Ionic capacitor running app on device java error

Tags: android, ionic-framework

So first what happend:
I created a new ionic app with `ionic start` and followed the installation wizard. After that I did run `ionic capacitor run` to test it on my device and that worked fine. After that test I edited my code and installed new modules etc and somehow destroyed my code.

So because I didn't do much I just created a new project to work on with `ionic start` and after that I run `ionic capacitor run` to test it on my device but that doesn't work anymore...

I don't know why this doesn't work anymore on a newly created project.

This is the error message:

```
[capacitor]         > Task :app:processDebugMainManifest FAILED
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         * What went wrong:
[capacitor]         Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugMainManifest'.
[capacitor]         > Unable to make field private final java.lang.String java.io.File.path accessible: module java.base does not "opens java.io" to unnamed module @47a5e3f0
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         * Try:
[capacitor]         Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 8.0.
[capacitor]         Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
[capacitor]         See https://docs.gradle.org/7.0/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
[capacitor]
[capacitor]         BUILD FAILED in 4s
[capacitor]         41 actionable tasks: 7 executed, 34 up-to-date
[capacitor]
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess capacitor.
```

Comment: Are you doing ionic start in same directory? If so, try deleting whole directory and start over from top.